# How can I perform a 3D transition animation that looks like a rectangular prism is rotating?

Tags: ios, uiview, cakeyframeanimation, catransform3d

I am trying to achieve a 3D transition animation where it looks like the first view is the front of a rectangular prism, and then the rectangular prism rotates forward until what was the top of it is now the front of it. I tried working with 3D transforms, but was unable to get it to work. For now I have an effect that uses scale, and it looks similar, but it doesn't have the right perspective effect:

```
// Add the new view to the view hierarchy
newView.frame = oldView.superview.bounds;
[oldView.superview addSubview:newView];

// Anchor to the top
newView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
newView.center = CGPointMake(newView.superview.bounds.size.width / 2, 0);

// Anchor to the bottom
oldView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
oldView.center = CGPointMake(newView.superview.bounds.size.width / 2, newView.superview.bounds.size.height);

// Animate the scale transform, not linearly in scale, but linearly in the area covered
NSInteger numberOfSteps = floorf(newView.superview.bounds.size.height);

CAKeyframeAnimation *newTransformAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
newTransformAnimation.duration = 0.4;
NSMutableArray *newValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger step = 0; step <= numberOfSteps; step++) {
    [newValues addObject:@((CGFloat)step / numberOfSteps)];
}
newTransformAnimation.values = newValues;
[newView.layer addAnimation:newTransformAnimation forKey:@"scale"];

CAKeyframeAnimation *oldTransformAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
oldTransformAnimation.duration = 0.4;
NSMutableArray *oldValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger step = 0; step <= numberOfSteps; step++) {
    [oldValues addObject:@((CGFloat)(numberOfSteps - step) / numberOfSteps)];
}
oldTransformAnimation.values = oldValues;
oldView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 0, 1);
[oldView.layer addAnimation:oldTransformAnimation forKey:@"scale"];

// Animate opacity
newView.alpha = 0.2;

[UIView
 animateWithDuration:0.4
 delay:0
 options:0
 animations:^{
     newView.alpha = 1;
     oldView.alpha = 0.2;
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     // Finally remove the old view from the view hierarchy
     [oldView removeFromSuperview];
 }];
```

If I understand correctly, I should be able to change the newTransformAnimation and oldTransformAnimation so that they apply a 3D effect instead of just a scale in the Y dimension. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** I know there are lots of sample projects all over the Internet that do something similar. I've been working with some of them and I just haven't been able to wrap my head around it. If someone understands this kind of thing and could explain it, that would be really appreciated.